# Last N items of any iterable via generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am working on a script that will return the last N items of any iterable as a list.

The following is working:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = (n**2 for n in range(10))


def tail(iterable, n):
    x = list(iterable)
    if n < 0:
        return []
    else:
        return list(x[-n:])


print(tail(b, 3))
print(tail(a, 4))
```

I want to make one last change.  If the iterable is enormous, say range(10000000), I don't want to produce the whole list up front.

I want to be memory efficient, i.e., use a generator.

I have made several attempts, including this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = (n**2 for n in range(10))


def tail(iterable, n):
    if n < 0:
        return []
    else:
        return list([(yield x) for x in iterable][-n:])


print(tail(b, 3))
```

But I run into the same error every time:
    TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

How can I modify my script to iterate over a generator instead of a list so that I produce the same output (must be a list) without creating a large
iterable up front.

Comment: You can't just get the last n. You have to go in sequential order with a generator, calculating everything before the last n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize a `deque` for this and specify its `maxlen` to `n`:

```
from collections import deque

def tail(iterable, n):
    if n < 0:
        return []
    else:
        return deque(iterable, n)
```

wrap the `return` in a `list` call to get the result back as a list if needed. The `deque` does not create an intermediate list out of the iterator thereby keeping the space complexity down.

Comment: And two minutes before I saw your post I ran into this:  https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch01s03.html